# Div created table appears to break in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

It works in IE and Safari but breaks in Chrome.  You can view the page here http://www.archemarks.com.

It only breaks at a middle zoom point so you have to zoom in and zoom out and at this middle point the table breaks.

This made me think it was something minor that as the browser re-drew the page..the changing pixels available caused it to make something bigger than normal...or smaller and broke the layout.

Chrome has development tools which should make all of the CSS and HTML available.

I tried fiddling witht the size of the text in put box and the containing column and row..but this did not help as I was only guessing.

Any non-guessing advice.

I can repost the code but it might be easier to just view the site using Chrome Development Tools

Comment: It only happens for me when I *zoom out* a couple of times. Actual users almost never zoom *out*, so I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: @thirtydot I was thinking the same thing, but this is the second question today about "when I zoom out it..." O_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the width of your .t2_c1 rule.  At only 100px, it isn't wide enough for the Email Again text.  this is undoubtedly because of the font size conversion being just slightly off as the browser compensates for the zoom.  Changing the .t2_c1 rule width to 110px and then the .t2_c2 width to 250px fixes this issue.

Comment: you are a godly....that particular solution...breaks the table...I just widened the entire table by 10px .t1...and..widened t2.c1 by 10Px per your suggestion....than I had to relative position the file upload row by 10px...pretty much what you said...b.c. file upload was odd ball out...I thought that was the cause..but i was wrong..